# Creating domain classes with foreign key constraints in groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Hi I am trying to create a domain class with foreign key constraint to another existing domain class
New domain class is ArEntitlement defined as below

```
package ars
import gra.Resources
class ArEntitlement {
    long id
    String entitlementname
    String entitlementdesc
    String entitlementcomm
    Integer departmentid
    Resources resource
    Integer version

    static belongsto =[resource : Resources]

    static mapping={
    table 'ar_entitlement'
    id(generator:'increment')
    column{
        id(column:'id')
        }
    }
}
```

Resource domain class is defined as follows (it was created before)

```
package gra
import com.gra.transaction.UserTransaction

class Resources {
    Long id=1
    String resourceName
    Double resourceType
    String resourceOwner
    Double riskScore
    Integer decommissioned
    String resourceClass
    Long resourceSegment
    String targetIp
    String resCriticality
    Long resourceGroup
    Integer disabled

    static hasMany=[userTransactions:UserTransaction]

    static mapping = {
        table 'resource'
        version false
        id(generator:'increment')
                column{
                        id(column:'id') }

    }
    static constraints=
    {
        resourceName(nullable:true,blank:false)
        resourceType(nullable:true,blank:false)
        resourceOwner(nullable:true,blank:false)
        riskScore(nullable:false,blank:false)
        decommissioned(nullable:false,blank:false)
        resourceClass(nullable:false,blank:false)
        resourceSegment(nullable:false,blank:false)
        targetIp(nullable:false,blank:false)
        resCriticality(nullable:true,blank:false)
        resourceGroup(nullable:false,blank:false)
        disabled(nullable:false,blank:false)
    }
}
```

The resulting tables created dont have a foreign key mapping of ar_entitlement table to resource table, it does create a column called 'resource_id' but without foreign key constraint.
I need it to be pointing to id column of resource table

I tried several options, not having the belongsto specifier, using hasOne (in both domain classes) but not getting required foreign key relationship.

Any Idea what the issue is here?

log error i get is

```
2011-12-21 19:50:17,258 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsuccessful: alter table ar_entitlement add index FKDCD6161FEFD54E5E (resourceid_id), add constraint FKDCD6161FEFD54E5E foreign key (resourceid_id) references resource (id)
```

Comment: Have you tried running the `alter table` statement from the error message directly on database?

Comment: Hi, I ran the alter table statement directly as is and it failed, but just found out that the id field of resource table is unsigned - which is why it was failing, when I made the resource_id in ar_entitlements table unsigned and ran the query again it was successful... now I want to know is how do i make the resource_id field in the domain class ArEntitlement to be unsigned directly so that i dont have to create the constraint manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove 'Resources resource' row from ArEntitlement.

```
static belongsTo = [resource : Resources]
```

Should cover that and having it defined twice might be the issue.  Also you shouldn't need to specify the table names, the id generator or id column as it appears you are using the GORM defaults.  Try removing these as well.

Here is the modified code...

```
package ars
import gra.Resources
class ArEntitlement {

    String entitlementname
    String entitlementdesc
    String entitlementcomm
    Integer departmentid
    Integer version

    static belongsTo = [resource : Resources]

    static mapping = {
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I ran the alter table statement directly as is and it failed, but just found out that the id field of resource table is unsigned - which is why it was failing, when I made the resource_id in ar_entitlements table unsigned and ran the query again it was successful... now I want to know is how do i make the resource_id field in the domain class ArEntitlement to be unsigned directly so that i dont have to create the constraint manually.

Comment: What database are you running on?  It sure sounds like it is not helping you out much here.

Comment: Not aware of an unsigned integer that is easily used in Grails as an id field.  To be honest, I haven't had such issues.  Remove the 'long id' as I did above and let Grails add it for you.

Comment: How will I save only ArEntitlement object without referencing Resources ?

Comment: It has been a while since I've been doing Grails, but if memory serves, you should still be able to simply do 'arEntitlementInstance.save()'